# MS Word for Mac, show outline on the left panel

Tags: ms-office, word-processor

In MS Word for Windows, I can see an outline panel that shows headings so that I can jump to desired section quickly. But I don't have such an outline panel in Word for Mac. 
It does not have 'view' tab in the ribbon.

I'm NOT talking about 'outline view' that you can choose on the lower-left corner of the window.
I want an outline displayed on the left-hand side and main text in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac Microsoft Word version 16.61 in 2022

View > Tick "Navigation Pane"

Comment: You need to select "Document Map" at the top of the sidebar, otherwise by default it shows thumbnnails of the pages

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

There is 'Show or hide the Sidebar' button on the toolbar.

I can choose 'Reviewing pane' from that button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this menu:

View > Sidebar > Navigation